# Cross-site scripting with Javascript framework

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js, ember.js, xss, javascript-framework

We are thinking about implementing our new module with a Javascript framework GUI and Java backend.
The plan is that we call Ajax calls from the GUI to get the data from the backend.

Our worry is (due to our inexperience) is that if we deploy  the GUI to `http://server1` and the Java backend to `http://server2`, then wont the relevant Ajax calls from server1 to server2 qualify as Cross site scripting?
How can we prevent this in javascript frameworks?

(We are looking at Angular, Knockout, Ember.js, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You basically need to specify, in the header of the response from the web service, which referers are allowed.

For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good point. My only concern is, why cant an attacker do this on the server they call? Or am i confused? :)

Comment: The response from the server is controlled by the application you've written yourself. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is in the response *from* the server, not the other way around. The actual check of the header is a security feature of the browser though. Might be worth to check compatibility as well: http://caniuse.com/#search=cors